# Matrix Calculation that Matches Numbers Contained within the Row and Column Names

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix that contains economic information on industries for several countries. I want to do a series of calculations that depend on the positioning of the element in the matrix and the corresponding column / row names.

The row / column names has a three letter country code followed by an industry number. The row and column names are identical.

The calculation would be as follows:

1. For each element in a row, there will be a matched country and industry
2. Keeping the industry combination the same, multiply the industry of purely the same country with the same one in the other country inside of the match.

I will give a simple example, although my data is much bigger than this example.

Say I have matrix `a`

```
set.seed(10)

a <- matrix(sample(36) , nrow = 6)
colnames(a) <- rownames(a) <- paste( rep(c("aaa" , "bbb" , "ccc") , each = 2), rep(c(1:2) , times = 3))
```

Giving:

```
      aaa 1 aaa 2 bbb 1 bbb 2 ccc 1 ccc 2
aaa 1     9    19    26     6     5    21
aaa 2    10    24     2    30    36    27
bbb 1    12    15    13    11    20    16
bbb 2     8    28    33    18    34    17
ccc 1    22    35    14    23    29     4
ccc 2     7    31    25    32     1     3
```

In this case there are three countries "aaa", "bbb" and "ccc" and only two industries, 1 and 2. I want to calculate the value of industries produced in their own countries and multiply with each other.

For example, in `a[1, 4]` this would match "aaa 1" with "bbb 2". I would want to multiply industry combination 1 - 2 for each country i.e. "aaa 1" - "aaa 2" with "bbb 1" - "bbb 2" (19 * 11 = 209). The values along the blocks of diagonals would be squared (two times the same country).

The final matrix would look like:

```
      aaa 1 aaa 2 bbb 1 bbb 2 ccc 1 ccc 2
aaa 1    81   361   117   209   261    76
aaa 2   100   576   330   432    10    72
bbb 1   117   209   169   121   377    44
bbb 2   330   432  1089   324    33    54
ccc 1   261    76   377    44   841    16
ccc 2    10    72    33    54     1     9
```

Which I calculated manually using this inefficient following code:

```
b <- kronecker(diag(1, 3), matrix(1, 2, 2))

b <- (a * b)^2
c <- b

c[1,3] <- 9 * 13
c[1,4] <- 19 * 11
c[1,5] <- 9 * 29
c[1,6] <- 19 * 4

c[2,3] <- 10 * 33
c[2,4] <- 24 * 18
c[2,5] <- 10 * 1
c[2,6] <- 24 * 3

.
.
.

c[6,1] <- 1 * 10
c[6,2] <- 3 * 24
c[6,3] <- 1 * 33
c[6,4] <- 3 * 18
```

Is there a flexible code to calculate this irrespective of the number of countries and industries within the data? I appreciate any help.

**Edit: The matrices I am working with are large (with dimensions of over 2000 * 2000). I would need a code that can handle this kind of data without freezing R. Unfortunately,** `outer` **can solve the problem posed here for lower smaller matrices, but gets stuck when working with larger ones.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this should perform well enough if your actual matrix `a` is `n`-by-`n` with `n` less than 10000. You can optimize further, especially if you know that `dimnames(a)` are sorted (see, e.g., @DarrenTsai's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75509955/12685768)), but it's not clearly necessary.

```r
n <- nrow(a)
nms <- rownames(a)

u <- unlist(strsplit(nms, " "))
country <- u[c(TRUE, FALSE)]
industry <- u[c(FALSE, TRUE)]

i1 <- seq_len(n)
j2 <- rep(i1, each = n)
j1 <- match(paste(country, industry[j2]), nms)
i2 <- match(paste(country[j2], industry), nms)

matrix(a[cbind(i1, j1)] * a[cbind(i2, j2)], n, n)
```

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]   81  361  117  209  261   76
[2,]  100  576  330  432   10   72
[3,]  117  209  169  121  377   44
[4,]  330  432 1089  324   33   54
[5,]  261   76  377   44  841   16
[6,]   10   72   33   54    1    9
```

Of course, if `dimnames(a)` aren't sorted but you want to reap the benefits of sortedness, then you can permute the rows and columns of `a`, operate on the resulting block matrix, and inverse permute the rows and columns of the answer.

```r
n <- nrow(a)
nms <- rownames(a)

## Number of industries, countries:
ni <- sum(startsWith(nms, substr(nms[1L], 1L, 3L)))
nc <- n %/% ni

p <- order(nms)
a.pp <- a[p, p] # permute

## Essentially @DarrenTsai's answer {uglier but highly optimized}:
k <- sequence(rep.int(ni, n), rep(seq.int(1L, n, ni), each = ni) + seq.int(0L, n * n - 1L, n))
b <- matrix(a.pp[k], ni, n)
r.pp <- b[rep.int(seq_len(ni), nc), ] * as.vector(b[, sequence(rep.int(nc, ni), seq_len(ni), ni)])

q <- p
q[q] <- seq_along(q)
r <- r.pp[q, q] # inverse permute
```

Actually, there is some neat matrix algebra here. Block `[i,j]` of `r.pp` is the elementwise product of blocks `[i,i]` and `[j,j]` of `a.pp`. Hence `r.pp` can be seen as a sort of block cross product of `b`, since `b` is the horizontal concatenation of the diagonal blocks of `a.pp`.

Answer (score 6):

Assume that each country has equal number of industries, and `dimnames(a)` are sorted well like A1, A2...Am, B1, B2, ...Bm. This approach takes advantage of vectorized computation and avoids indexing the matrix with its dimnames, and hence improves the efficiency and saves memory considerably.

- `m`: number of industries

```r
m <- 2
n <- nrow(a)
block <- matrix(a[kronecker(diag(n/m), matrix(1, m, m)) == 1], m)
block[rep(1:m, len = n), ] * c(block[, c(t(matrix(1:n, m)))])

#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
# [1,]   81  361  117  209  261   76
# [2,]  100  576  330  432   10   72
# [3,]  117  209  169  121  377   44
# [4,]  330  432 1089  324   33   54
# [5,]  261   76  377   44  841   16
# [6,]   10   72   33   54    1    9
```

Answer (score 5):

Another way sub-setting the original matrix to the needed sub-matrixes and multiplying them (GKi1).

```
x <- do.call(rbind, strsplit(rownames(a), " "))
x <- apply(outer(unique(x[,1]), unique(x[,2]), paste), 1,
           \(i) a[i, i], simplify = FALSE)
x <- do.call(rbind, lapply(x, \(y) do.call(cbind, lapply(x, `*`, y))))
rownames(x) <- colnames(x)
x
#      aaa 1 aaa 2 bbb 1 bbb 2 ccc 1 ccc 2
#aaa 1    81   361   117   209   261    76
#aaa 2   100   576   330   432    10    72
#bbb 1   117   209   169   121   377    44
#bbb 2   330   432  1089   324    33    54
#ccc 1   261    76   377    44   841    16
#ccc 2    10    72    33    54     1     9

x[rownames(a), colnames(a)] #In case the order of the original matrix is needed
```

A variant, extracting the relevant information of the original matrix in a different way - similar to the comment from @Mikael Jagan (Thanks!) could look like (GKi1B).

```
n <- nrow(a)
x <- do.call(rbind, strsplit(rownames(a), " ", TRUE))
x1 <- unique(x[,1])
x2 <- unique(x[,2])
n1 <- length(x1)
n2 <- length(x2)
A <- a[rep(match(t(outer(unique(x[,1]), unique(x[,2]), paste)), rownames(a)), each=n2) +
       sequence(rep.int(n2, n), sequence(rep.int(n2, n1), seq.int(0L, by=n*n2, length.out=n1), n-1L))]
do.call(rbind, lapply(seq.int(0, by=n2*n2, length.out=n1),
                      \(i) matrix(A * A[seq_len(n2*n2)+i], n2)) )
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#[1,]   81  361  117  209  261   76
#[2,]  100  576  330  432   10   72
#[3,]  117  209  169  121  377   44
#[4,]  330  432 1089  324   33   54
#[5,]  261   76  377   44  841   16
#[6,]   10   72   33   54    1    9
```

Another way using `outer` but might also work with a larger matrix could be (GKi2).

```
n <- rownames(a)
i <- do.call(rbind, strsplit(n, " "))
j <- outer(i[,1], i[,2], paste)
array(a[cbind(n, c(j))] * a[cbind(c(t(j)), n[col(a)])], dim(a))
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#[1,]   81  361  117  209  261   76
#[2,]  100  576  330  432   10   72
#[3,]  117  209  169  121  377   44
#[4,]  330  432 1089  324   33   54
#[5,]  261   76  377   44  841   16
#[6,]   10   72   33   54    1    9
```

---

Benchmark

```
set.seed(10)
a <- matrix(sample(1:100, 2002*2002, TRUE) , nrow = 2002)
colnames(a) <- rownames(a) <- paste( rep(strrep(letters, 3) , each = 77), 1:77)

bench::mark(check=FALSE,
ThomasIsCoding = {p <- expand.grid(rep(list(row.names(a)), 2))
p1 <- as.matrix(transform(p, Var2 = paste(sub("\\d+", "", Var1), sub("\\D+", "", Var2), sep = "")))
p2 <- as.matrix(transform(p, Var1 = paste(sub("\\d+", "", Var2), sub("\\D+", "", Var1), sep = "")))
`dim<-`(a[p1] * a[p2], dim(a))},
"Mikael Jagan" = {n <- nrow(a)
nms <- rownames(a)
u <- unlist(strsplit(nms, " "))
country <- u[c(TRUE, FALSE)]
industry <- u[c(FALSE, TRUE)]
i1 <- seq_len(n)
j2 <- rep(i1, each = n)
j1 <- match(paste(country, industry[j2]), nms)
i2 <- match(paste(country[j2], industry), nms)
matrix(a[cbind(i1, j1)] * a[cbind(i2, j2)], n, n)},
GKi2 = {n <- rownames(a)
i <- do.call(rbind, strsplit(n, " "))
j <- outer(i[,1], i[,2], paste)
array(a[cbind(n, c(j))] * a[cbind(c(t(j)), n[col(a)])], dim(a))},
"Mikael & Darren" = {n <- nrow(a)
nms <- rownames(a)
ni <- sum(startsWith(nms, substr(nms[1L], 1L, 3L)))
nc <- n %/% ni
p <- order(nms)
a.pp <- a[p, p] # permute
b <- matrix(a.pp[as.logical(kronecker(diag(nc), matrix(1, ni, ni)))], ni, n)
r.pp <- b[rep.int(seq_len(ni), nc), ] * as.vector(b[, sequence(rep.int(nc, ni), seq_len(ni), ni)])
q <- p
q[q] <- seq_along(q)
r.pp[q, q]},
GKi1 = {x <- do.call(rbind, strsplit(rownames(a), " "))
x <- apply(outer(sort(unique(x[,1])), sort(unique(x[,2])), paste), 1,
           \(i) a[i, i], simplify = FALSE)
x <- do.call(rbind, lapply(x, \(y) do.call(cbind, lapply(x, `*`, y))))
rownames(x) <- colnames(x)
x},
"Mikael & DarrenB" = {n <- nrow(a)
nms <- rownames(a)
ni <- sum(startsWith(nms, substr(nms[1L], 1L, 3L)))
nc <- n %/% ni
p <- order(nms)
a.pp <- a[p, p] # permute
b <- {k <- sequence(rep.int(ni, n), rep(seq.int(1L, n, ni), each = ni) + seq(0L, n * n - 1L, n)); matrix(a.pp[k], ni, n)}
r.pp <- b[rep.int(seq_len(ni), nc), ] * as.vector(b[, sequence(rep.int(nc, ni), seq_len(ni), ni)])
q <- p
q[q] <- seq_along(q)
r.pp[q, q]},
GKi1B = {n <- nrow(a)
x <- do.call(rbind, strsplit(rownames(a), " ", TRUE))
x1 <- unique(x[,1])
x2 <- unique(x[,2])
n1 <- length(x1)
n2 <- length(x2)
A <- a[rep(match(t(outer(unique(x[,1]), unique(x[,2]), paste)), rownames(a)), each=n2) +
       sequence(rep.int(n2, n), sequence(rep.int(n2, n1), seq.int(0L, by=n*n2, length.out=n1), n-1L))]
do.call(rbind, lapply(seq.int(0, by=n2*n2, length.out=n1),
                      \(i) matrix(A * A[seq_len(n2*n2)+i], n2))) }
)
```

Result

```
  expression            min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc
  <bch:expr>       <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>
1 ThomasIsCoding      1.24s    1.24s     0.810   872.1MB     4.05     1     5
2 Mikael Jagan     743.23ms 743.23ms     1.35    367.1MB     1.35     1     1
3 GKi2             812.95ms 812.95ms     1.23    734.1MB     4.92     1     4
4 Mikael & Darren   62.56ms  64.66ms    15.5     140.7MB     9.69     8     5
5 GKi1              28.72ms  29.57ms    33.3      48.8MB     7.83    17     4
6 Mikael & DarrenB  28.21ms  32.37ms    30.9      48.9MB     5.79    16     3
7 GKi1B              26.7ms   28.3ms    35.0      49.8MB     9.71    18     5
```

In this case Mikael & DarrenB, GKi1 and GKiB are the fastest and uses lowest amount of memory.

Answer (score 4):

You can try the code below

```
> p <- expand.grid(rep(list(row.names(a)), 2))

> p1 <- as.matrix(transform(p, Var2 = paste(sub("\\d+", "", Var1), sub("\\D+", "", Var2), sep = "")))

> p2 <- as.matrix(transform(p, Var1 = paste(sub("\\d+", "", Var2), sub("\\D+", "", Var1), sep = "")))

> `dim<-`(a[p1] * a[p2], dim(a))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]   81  361  117  209  261   76
[2,]  100  576  330  432   10   72
[3,]  117  209  169  121  377   44
[4,]  330  432 1089  324   33   54
[5,]  261   76  377   44  841   16
[6,]   10   72   33   54    1    9
```